# SearchBar for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar

I would like to implement UISearchBar in my app. My app consists of a view with a text in the middle, and by swiping left or right you get the same view but with another text.

My goal is to add UISearchBar that searches threw array of messages and then shows the results in tableview (that will appear after you start searching, I have no tableview right now in my app).

Any suggestions ??!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a UISearchDisplayController
have a look at these tutorials [Link1](http://cocoabob.net/?p=67)
and [Link2](http://blog.patrickcrosby.com/2010/04/27/iphone-ipad-uisearchbar-uisearchdisplaycontroller-asynchronous-example.html)

Comment: I have looked for those but they all search some tableview and then that tableview is added as datasource to searchdisplaycontroller but i don't have any tableview, just array...

Comment: have a look here  [link](http://ygamretuta.me/2011/08/10/ios-implementing-a-basic-search-uisearchdisplaycontroller-and-interface-builder/) you have to only use a UISearchDisplayController instead of a UiSearchbar, the UISearchDisplayController it has a tableView by default

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing, for searching from the list of Array you can use NSPredicate class to get the searched object form array list.

And then use the same Array as datasource for the UITableView. And reload its content.